# Html5 Canvas: alternative for drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Since I faced some rounding issues* with the default scale()-function of canvas I've implemented my own matrix-transformations for canvas. This is working fine with a sole exception, I cannot rotate an image because the drawImage() function can only be parameterized with the top left corner of the picture.

Is there any other method to draw an image on a canvas? A method that can be parameterized with at least the coordinates for the top, left and the bottom right corner?, so that I can manually rotate the coordinates?

*The issue is a one-pixel-gap between shapes after scaling by a factor < 1.

Comment: You can use Context2D.transform(... whole matrix ...) before drawImage(). Everything should work. What is the problem?

Comment: There's no alternative to context.rotate.  Perhaps try to fix that 1 pixel gap?

Comment: The 1 pixel-gap results from scaling integers by floats. If you scale 1 by 1/3 you end up with 0.333333... But pixels are discrete. I have the 1/3 in the matrix, so I don't think that it would solve the problem if I use Context2D.transform() instead of scale(). I have to round the result of the transformation (matrix multiplication).

Comment: One option: increase the drawImage width & height by 1/2 pixel.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "ParseInt"

Comment: Ignore that deleted comment (I temporarily spaced out and thought you were drawing paths but I see you're drawing images).

Comment: Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/6KZ4Z/

Comment: the smaller box has a gap in the middle. (I'm using boxes here just to show what I mean, but originally I wanted to draw an image)

Comment: Yep, increase the size of the rects (or images) by 1/2 pixel to accommodate the gap.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6KZ4Z/2/

Answer (score 1):

Based off of your fiddle in the comments you could use an in memory canvas as a back buffer to draw what you need to at normal size, then scale the context of your main canvas and use `drawImage` to draw the scaled result.

[image]

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/6KZ4Z/3/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var backBuffer = document.createElement("canvas"),
    bCtx = backBuffer.getContext("2d");

paint = function (x, y, scale) {

    bCtx.clearRect(0,0,backBuffer.width,backBuffer.height);;
    bCtx.beginPath();
    bCtx.rect(x, y, 30, 30);
    bCtx.fillStyle = 'black';
    bCtx.fill();

    bCtx.beginPath();
    bCtx.rect(x + 30, y, 30, 30);
    bCtx.fillStyle = 'black';
    bCtx.fill();

    context.save();
    context.scale(scale,scale);
    context.drawImage(backBuffer,0,0);
    context.restore();
}

paint(10, 10, 1);
paint(10, 70, .66);
```

Comment: This indeed would work. I want to use the state-stack with several transformations where the transformation of a lower stack-layer are also applied to higher stack-layers. If some parts of the transformation are applied on a different canvas, this might lead to pretty complex code... thats why I try to find another solution... but maybe there is no...